# Query SVN repository from ASP.NET to get revision history

Tags: asp.net, svn

I want to query my SVN repository from an ASP.NET application to list the top XX latest revisions of my application.

What's the best way to do this? execute a shell execute command against the svn command line app? or can i access it via https?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Collabnet have a open source product called [SharpSVN](http://sharpsvn.open.collab.net/); which is a .NET 2.0 client API for subversion.